# Leaking Shower Handle

Tags: plumbing, leak, plumbing-fixture

Our outdoor shower is leaking. All the water is coming from right behind the handle. Do I need to replace the whole unit or can I just replace the cartridge?

[image]

Video here:
https://youtu.be/ETXY8khsHw0

Comment: Looks like more than just a cartage replacement.  Do hope you have turned off the water.  Will need to check bottom of inside of the wall to dry it out.

Comment: Turn off the water at that location  and remove those four screws. There's either a blown "o"ring  or that white piece has cracked.

Comment: thanks -- will try both of those

Comment: I removed the cartridge. There are two O-rings and one was completely out. I put it back in correctly and the leak remains.

Comment: Replaced the cartridge and everything works well. I'm not sure if it was the cartridge or the o-rings. The overall fix was $25. Thanks for the help.